# Nvidia drivers Issues

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I am fairly new to ubuntu and linux and I have been trying to get it setup on my new alienware 15 r2 for the last 4 days. I have trouble with the wifi, but I just use a tplink usb wifi dongle now. But I have been struggling with the nvidia drivers. I have now gone through every article here I could find and I either end up with a black screen with a flickering cursor or an infinit login loop. I purge all nvidia drivers and everything works fine again. I have gone through every proposed solution for each of the problems I encounter and no change. I don't know if it's a compatibility issue, or if it's something I am doing wrong but I have put a ton of hours into this and I would very much like it resolved.

I'm dual booting Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with windows 10, with a GTX965M Nvidia card and a Intel HD Graphics 530. I have heard that optimus could cause these problems and I have tried with Bumblebee, but no dice. Could someone please give me a step-by-step solution to this? Like I said it might be something I'm doing wrong and I am new, so I would appreciate the assumed details, or at least a hint so that I can research it myself.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Generally it is recommended to use the NVIDIA drivers from the official Ubuntu repositories.
But as you have very new graphics hardware, you can install the latest official NVIDIA drivers.

Step 1 : Uninstall every NVIDIA related software that is currently installed.

Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

On the login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> - enter user name and password - execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia* bumblebee  
sudo reboot
```

Step 2 : Install the latest official NVIDIA drivers that support the GTX 965M.

Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

On the login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> - enter user name and password - execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Use NVIDIA X Server Settings (PRIME Profiles) to switch between the Intel and NVIDIA graphics.
Note : Check whether there have settings to be changed in BIOS to manage the NVIDIA graphics.

Comment: I have tried all of that, although I don't remember explicitly adding the 

`nvidia-prime` 

Code at the end of that line. I will try that a little later, just downloading stuff in windows. What does that bit actually do? Also, Which BIOS are you talking about? Because I know how to get into the one you usually would use if your just running windows, is that what you are talking about? Thanks, btw :)

Comment: @Rian199 : nvidia-prime is the software which will let you switch between intel and NVIDIA graphics. :)

Comment: Thanks @cl-netbox .Btw, I followed these steps right after fresh install (http://scienceblogs.com/gregladen/2014/04/24/10-or-20-things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr/  &&  http://howtoubuntu.org/things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr). Will any of those steps cause issues with the nvidia drivers? And are there extra things I would need to do besides those steps, and the ones you outlined above before installing the drivers?

Comment: @Rian199 : No this should not cause any issues and you don't have to do anything else before performing the NVIDIA drivers installation - follow exactly the instructions given in the answer and everything should work ... :)

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'm gonna try it now and see if it works. One more question though. The only reason I want to install these drivers is because I want to utilise CUDA purely for computing power. Is there any way to work around the drivers, in case this doesn't work, without having to install the actual drivers? My understanding about how it all works might be wrong, but it was just a thought, leaving the nouveau drivers in place but using the nvdiia card for running some programs through?

Comment: @Rian199 : When you don't install the NVIDIA drivers you are always using the integrated intel graphics. :)

Comment: But does that get me access to the cuda cores parallel computing power still? Also, I am currently installing the drivers as we speak, just before I need to reboot the final time. What do those final sentences mean i.e. "Use NVIDIA X Server Settings (PRIME Profiles) to switch between the Intel and NVIDIA graphics.
Note : Check whether there have settings to be changed in BIOS to manage the NVIDIA graphics."?

Comment: @Rian199 : Of course you can access cuda cores - Cuda ia a NVIDIA product. In some cases (mostly not) you have to switch settings in BIOS - every hardware is different. :)

Comment: Okay, so I did everything exactly as you said and everything boots, including grub, and I eventually reach a black screen at the login page. I know it reaches the login page because that ubuntu drum sound plays, but no visual. I can enter the console by pressing ctr+alt+F1, and that works. If I then press ctr+alt+F7 to return, the text displayed in the console is still displayed on the screen but you can see the curser stops flickering (i.e. inactive of some sort). I press ctrl+alt+F1 again, and the cursor starts blinking again. Same problem I had before. Any thoughts?

Comment: It's almost as if the display wasn't plugged in as soon as it reaches the login page?

Comment: @Rian199 Did you have an external monitor attached when installing the drivers ? In case yes - unplug it and repeat everything ! :)

Comment: No i didnt, sorry, I just meant that it was like that, there was sound but no display. Since this happens after setting the `nouveau.modeset=0`, and installing the driver, is it possible that Ubuntu can't get access to the Nvidia card forsome reason?

Comment: @Rian199 : No, this is not possible - setting the parameter this way is a one time solution to disable the nouveau drivers during the installation process. :)

Comment: Oh okay, yea I see that now looking at the grub again. So any ideas of what I could try next?

Comment: HI @cl-netbox : I just had it working for a second and now it's down again :/ see my answer I posted, any insights?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing drivers from software and updates in ubuntu ,
go to Additional drivers tab and it will show the drivers for Nvidia cards

or

https://www.nvidia.in/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-in

download the `.run` driver files

`chmod +x filename.run
sudo sh filename.run`

Comment: Yes I have done that. I get an option of two nvidia drivers in the additional drivers tab, one for for binary nvidia 35(something; cant remember exactly), and a second which is exactly the same as the other one, but has "updates" tacked on at the end. Choosing either one and applying changes takes a long time, but after it has finished and I reboot, I get the login loop again. Then I have to purge, and login works fine after that.

Comment: I have also downloaded the .run drivers directly, for all available compatible drivers with my card (nvidia-361, 355 and 352(i think)). I stop all X-server (I think that was it) operations because that interferes with the installation as well as the nouveau drivers, then Installs, it builds the driver, tells me the installation was succesfull etc. but still the login loop problem. I think it was with the 355 driver that I just get a black screen with a flickering cursor, and I have to ctr+alt+F1, purge again to be able to login again. I also clean installed several times.Any other suggestions?

Comment: login loop may be the issue with the .Xauthority file .seems you need to change the ownership of that file by  `sudo chown username:username .Xauthority`

Comment: I have done that twice before...no luck, sorry

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: THE SOLUTION BELOW WORKED BUT THEN I REBOOTED AND NOW IT'S NOT WORKING ANYMORE AND I'M BACK TO THE SAME ISSUE :(

UPDATE 2: SEEMS THAT IF I PLAY AROUND WITH

`prime-select intel` -
`service lightdm restart` -
`sync`-

and

`prime-select nvidia` - 
`service lightdm restart` -
`sync` -
It seems to work but a "System program problem detected" dialog box to appear at random.

I think it's fixed!
followed the instructions on this (Answer #20):
https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/810964/black-screen-after-prime-select-nvidia-and-log-out-using-v346-35-drivers/?offset=16

I didnt find the files " /usr/lib/primeindicator/igpuon and /usr/lib/primeindicator/dgpuon " that he suggests, although simply adding the replacing `sh` with `bash` in the file /sbin/prime-offload and then switching back to the GUI by pressing ctr+alt+F7 made my login screen re-apear, and login is fine.

Ran

`sudo lspci -v1`

And i can see the last line under the 3D-graphic controller is

`Kernel driver in use: nvidia`

That means it's installed and working right?